# OOM kills Python calculation in terminal via remote but not in a ssh

Tags: command-line, ssh, python, ram, remote

I don’t know why my Python calculation is running when I am using an ssh connection to a Linux machine (Ubuntu).

The same calculation doesn’t work when I run it in a terminal via remote connection.

The latter one is more convenient, because I can shut down my PC and it continues to run.

The calculation needs a lot of ram, I habe about 100 Gb swap. I reckon it is the OOM killer, but I am not sure.

Have anyone a clue?

Thanks,
Arch

Comment: Your question title and the first two sentences seem to contradict each other. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1480755/edit) and add what protocol you use when you use "a terminal via remote connection." Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Are using using the Gnome Remote Sharing feature built into Ubuntu 22.04 and later in your remote Ubuntu computer?

Comment: How do you run your python script from while connected via `ssh`? Add the exact command. Normally `ssh` opens a new session and when you close the `ssh` connection that session ends including whatever you were running in that session such as your python script.

Comment: See answers to [Execute script remotely over SSH and disconnect from running process?](https://superuser.com/questions/1425756/execute-script-remotely-over-ssh-and-disconnect-from-running-process)